# CodeIgniter Template Parser Convert MultiDimensional Array To Single

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, templates, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array for `$this->data`

```
Array
(
    [icon] => http://localhost/uploads/icon.png
    [logo] => http://localhost/uploads/logo.svg
    [seo] => Array
        (
            [canonical] => http://localhost/profile/register/
            [title] => Register
        )
)
```

How do I change the above to

```
Array
(
    [icon] => http://localhost/uploads/icon.png
    [logo] => http://localhost/uploads/logo.svg
    [canonical] => http://localhost/profile/register/
    [title] => Register
)
```

And what happens if I have another `[icon]` (a duplicate) under the `[seo]` will the first `[icon]` gets replace or ignore or how when I change it like above? The reason I need to convert it into single array because when I send the data for parsing, I can't get the `{canonical}` and `{title}` to work.

`$this->data['seo']` from `Profile_Controller.php` will replace `$this->data` from `MY_Controller.php` so right now, I'm doing a workaround like putting those seo data into another array and use `array_merge` but I think there's another better way around it...

Comment: Wht's about {seo[canonical]} ?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work... `{seo[title]}` not working as well... If someone could teach me how to pull those [canonical] and [title] up 1 level array, it is possible to parse. My only workaround right now is to assign those seo arrays into a new string then I use `array_merge` to combine them back to `$this->data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a foreach it's pretty easy. Just assign the array keys of seo to the main array and then unset the seo array from the main array:

```
   <?php
    $arr = [
        'icon' => 'http://localhost/uploads/icon.png',
        'logo' => 'http://localhost/uploads/logo.svg',
        'seo' => [
                'canonical' => 'http://localhost/profile/register/',
                'title' => 'Register'
            ]
    ];

        echo '<pre>';

        print_r($arr);

        foreach ($arr['seo'] as $k => $v) {
            $arr[$k] = $v;
        }
        unset($arr['seo']);

        print_r($arr);
```

If there is a duplicate `icon` in the `seo` array it will overwrite the one in the master array.